# Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect monitor using type-c DisplayPort

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, displayport

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Laptop DELL G3 3500
Graphics card: NVIDIA Corporation / GeForce GTX 1650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 (from system settings)

I've used to connect my second monitor using type-c displayport, but it seems not to detect it anymore.

Tried to install and reinstall NVIDIA drivers versions 390, 435, 440, 450, 460, 465.
Updated and reinstalled displaylink driver.
Secure boot is disabled in BIOS.
Tried different prime profiles for NVIDIA.

xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-5-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    120.04*+  59.97    59.96    60.01    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

DP-1-1 seems to be like there should be connected via type-c monitor.
Type C cable is working, monitor too, tested on another laptops.

When I connect another monitor to my laptop using HDMI - it works, when I connect it using type-c=>type-c (displayport) cable - it does not work.

Laptop like does not react any way on type-c monitor connected.
Type-c in laptop is working, when I connect a type-c hub with connected ethernet cable, headphones, keyboard, mouse and monitor - everything works except a monitor wich is connected via HDMI to the hub.

Tried also all another found solutions from different threads - it doesn't help :(

**Previously some time ago I used to connect the same monitor to the same laptop using type-c and it used to work nice.**

lshw output:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:158 memory:82000000-82ffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:83080000-830fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:157 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Other additional info:

```
$ cat /boot/config-5.8.0-59-generic | grep TYPEC_DP
CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE=m
```

using sudo journalctl -f and then plugged\unplugged type-c cable - nothing appeared

```
$ uname -a
Linux astronb 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Trying to wake DP-1-1 manually:

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1-1 --auto
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  65
  Current serial number in output stream:  67

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)

$ lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       57344  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              241664  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
```

Help, please.

Comment: $ xrandr --output DP-1 --auto
makes no output, DP-1 in xradr output keeps disconnected

Comment: any solutions till now ?

Comment: No, I didn't find the solution, so I deleted completely all drivers of NVIDIA by full reinstalling of my Ubuntu system and now using Intel Graphics. If there will be solution - I'll be glad to use my NVIDIA GPU in that laptop

Comment: I didn't understand, did your Type-c worked with other monitor ?
I found that my laptop's type-c port doesn't support video output, only charging, transferring data .. etc. It's neither thunderbolt, nor has Alt Mode (which actually is something like 2 in 1 dp port + type-c). Check if your type-c is alt mode one.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the similar issue as yours, however I'm using Intel Xe Graphics on my ThinkPad X13 Yoga.

I managed to make the monitor work via type-c to HDMI dock by simply **not to plug the dock in until logged into Ubuntu**.

Once I plug the dock before powering the laptop, Ubuntu will display several pci related error during startup as below, and will never recognize the monitor whatever I try.

```
$sudo dmesg
[    0.583417] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
[   30.821715] ACPI Error: Aborting method \IPCS due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20210730/psparse-529)
[   30.821732] ACPI Error: Aborting method \MCUI due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20210730/psparse-529)
[   30.821741] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SPCX due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20210730/psparse-529)
[   30.821750] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG0.PON due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20210730/psparse-529)
[   30.821759] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG0.PXP._ON due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

X11 or wayland both work on Ubuntu 22.04.1 .

```
$ uname-a
Linux X13-Yoga 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```